# What does “'str' object is not callable” mean?

Tags: python

I'm learning classes, but I'm unsure on why this does not work:

---

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, fname, lname, login, password, email, nickname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.nickname = nickname
        print('Thank you')

    def login(self, log, pas):
        if log == self.login and pas!= self.password:
            print('The password you entered is incorrect')
        elif log != self.login and pas == self.password:
            print('The login you entered is incorrect')
        elif log != self.login and pas != self.password:
            print('cannot find that account')
        else:
            print(f"Welcome {self.nickname}")
            return True


firstname = input('What is your first name? ')

lastname = input('What is your last name? ')

login_name = input('What  would your login be? ')

your_password = input('What would your password be? ')

your_email = input('What is your email? ')

your_nickname = input('What would you like to be called? ')

user_1 = User(firstname, lastname, login_name, your_password, your_email, your_nickname)

access = False

while access == False

log_name = input('Login: ')

log_pass = input('Password: ')

access = user_1.login('log_name', 'log_pass')
```

Comment: It keeps coming back as 'str' object is not callable whenever i go to login section at the bottom

Comment: Try to `print(user_1.login)` before `access = user_1.login('log_name', 'log_pass')`.

Comment: Change `self.login` to `self.username`.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of a class can only have one thing assigned to a given name at a time. In this case, your class has two:

- the method `login()`, which is added when the class is created
- the variable `login`, which overwrites the above when `__init__()` runs.

You'll need to rename either the method or the variable to something else, so that they can coexist peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to rename your method:

```
class User:
  def __init__(self, fname, lname, login, password, email, nickname):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.login = login
    self.password = password
    self.email = email
    self.nickname = nickname
    print('Thank you')

  def check_login(self, log, pas):
    if log == self.login and pas!= self.password:
        print('The password you entered is incorrect')
    elif log != self.login and pas == self.password:
        print('The login you entered is incorrect')
    elif log != self.login and pas != self.password:
        print('cannot find that account')
    else:
        print(f"Welcome {self.nickname}")
        return True

firstname = input('What is your first name? ')
lastname = input('What is your last name? ')
login_name = input('What would your login be? ')
your_password = input('What would your password be? ')
your_email = input('What is your email? ')
your_nickname = input('What would you like to be called? ')
user_1 = User(firstname, lastname, login_name, your_password, your_email, your_nickname)
access = False
while access == False:
  log_name = input('Login: ')
  log_pass = input('Password: ')
  access = user_1.check_login(log_name, log_pass)
```

Comment: Aren't dunders usually reserved for built-in language features? `__init__`, `__str__`, etc. He should probably just rename his login variable to a different word, like `user` or something.

Comment: Well I just put it as an example because I don't think there is a built-in function `__login__` in Python. Although it isn't recommended, I use them when I to the best of my knowledge know that it won't conflict with a built-in function.

Thanks for you suggestion. I've edited my answer.